# CSS Gradient height for IE?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

In the webkit and moz vendor specific properties for CSS gradients, you can specify the height of the gradient. Is there something similar for IE?

For example:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#aaaaaa', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 3, from(#aaaaaa), to(#ffffff)); /* webkit */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #aaaaaa,  #ffffff 3px); /* firefox */
```

How can I specify a 3px high gradient in IE?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no way to set the height expect by setting the height of the element you are applying it to. So to get `3px` you would need a `3px` tall `div` to use it on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, but you could create a duplicate div with a defined height of 3px and apply the IE filter to that.

Or you could avoid the IE code bloat, and accept that IE will have a different aesthetic than more capable browsers (square corners included).